Dependency Error in Railway even though the dependency is actually not listed

I'm getting this error even though there is no "zee5" dependency in my django app. I checked this through
How should I fix this issue?
pip list

I checked the installed packages in my environment to ensure that zee5 is not inadvertently installed.

can you genrate requirement.txt file and share here for better understanding of issue. command for that is pip freeze > requirement.txt

Oh my gosh!! I checked this soo late :(
It's really long so i can't put it here... https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QSibE5fRtyc8Le3Vyead0Yx1H6CV-E4Y9wDKwAFYHjI/edit?usp=sharing

I suggest, if your virturalenv have lots of unknown/useless packages, better to create new virtualenv and install what is required one by one.
